# URL Page Name Without Php ID

Tags: php, get

I have any Url with php extension eg:

```
http://localhost/test/admin/users.php
http://localhost/test/admin/list.php
http://localhost/test/admin/dates.php
```

Now For print menu ( navigation ) I Have This :

```
$pagename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') . '';

if ($pagename = "users") {echo "true";} else {}
```

My Methods Not Work! How To Get PHP page name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `==` (or `===`), not `=` in your `if` statement.

You are currently assigning the string "users" to the variable `$pagename`, so that always evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I told you, use == to compare if $pagename equals "users".

Comment: The better way would be to use ===, this way you check for both the value and the type of the variable ( 1 === 1 TRUE, 1 === 2 FALSE, "1" === 1 FALSE).

Answer (score 1):

incorrect IF:

```
if ($pagename == "users") {echo "true";} else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and get the file name like this

> ```
> $self = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PATHINFO_BASENAME);
>  $self=explode('.',$self);
>    if( $self[0]=="users"){
>    do...
>      }
>   else{}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and parse that value:

```
$self = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PATHINFO_BASENAME);
if($self == "users")
    //do something
else
    //do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function current_page_name()
 {
   $url = explode('/',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   $current_url = $url[count($url)-1];
   return $current_url;
 }  
 current_page_name();

 Hope this will help you?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function currentPageNameByURL()
{
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
    {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    else
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```